# $Q$ function and the Chernoff bound

Tags: probability, inequality, normal-distribution

How do we use the Chernoff bound to prove that

$$ Q(x)\leq e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}} $$

where $Q(x)$ is the probability that a standard normal random variable $X$ takes a value greater than $x$

Comment: What's $Q$?  Probability integral?

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$Q(x) = \mathbb{P}(X>x) \leq \mathbb{E} \big( e^{\lambda \cdot X- \lambda \cdot x} \big) = e^{-\lambda \cdot x} \mathbb{E}e^{\lambda \cdot X}$$

for any $\lambda > 0$. Since $X$ is a standard normal random variable, the exponential moment can be calculated explicitely; in fact,

$$\mathbb{E}e^{\lambda \cdot X} = e^{\lambda^2/2}.$$

Hence,

$$Q(x) \leq e^{-\lambda \cdot x} e^{\lambda^2/2}$$

In particular, we can choose $\lambda=x$, then

$$Q(x) \leq e^{-x^2/2}.$$